# AS3 - Automatically fill lineTo when it makes a closed loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have been looking at Emanuele Feronato's string avoider code (code and link below) and trying to adapt it so that when the string intersects itself - makes a closed loop - it only fills that area [see image](http://samtripp.com/eg.png). My maths is terrible and i'm struggling to make sense of the trig. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Here is a diagram to help clarify - http://samtripp.com/eg.png

LINK: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/10/13/develop-a-flash-game-like-string-avoider-as3-version-and-more/

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Point;
public class Main extends Sprite {
    private var tailLenght:Number=50;
    private var tailNodes:Number=10;
    private var head:headMc=new headMc();
    private var tailCanvas:Sprite=new Sprite();
    private var nodes:Vector.<Point>=new Vector.<Point>();
    public function Main() {
        addChild(head);
        head.x=320;
        head.y=240;
        addChild(tailCanvas);
        for (var i:int=0; i<tailNodes; i++) {
            nodes[i]=new Point(head.x,head.y);
        }
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
    }
    private function update(e:Event):void {
        head.x=mouseX;
        head.y=mouseY;
        tailCanvas.graphics.clear();
        tailCanvas.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x00ff00);
        tailCanvas.graphics.moveTo(head.x,head.y);
        nodes[0]=new Point(head.x,head.y);
        for (var i:int=1; i<tailNodes-1; i++) {
            var nodeAngle:Number=Math.atan2(nodes[i].y-nodes[i-1].y,nodes[i].x-nodes[i-1].x);
            nodes[i]=new Point(nodes[i-1].x+tailLenght*Math.cos(nodeAngle),nodes[i-1].y+tailLenght*Math.sin(nodeAngle));
            if (i<tailNodes-2) {
                for (var j:int=i-1; j>=1; j--) {
                    var p:Point=lineIntersection(nodes[j],nodes[j-1],nodes[i],nodes[i+1]);
                    if (p!=null) {
                        tailCanvas.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
                        tailCanvas.graphics.drawCircle(p.x,p.y,4);
                        tailCanvas.graphics.endFill();
                        tailCanvas.graphics.moveTo(nodes[i-1].x,nodes[i-1].y);
                    }
                }
            }
            tailCanvas.graphics.lineTo(nodes[i].x,nodes[i].y);
        }
    }
    private function lineIntersection(p1:Point,p2:Point,p3:Point,p4:Point):Point {
        var x1:Number=p1.x;
        var x2:Number=p2.x;
        var x3:Number=p3.x;
        var x4:Number=p4.x;
        var y1:Number=p1.y;
        var y2:Number=p2.y;
        var y3:Number=p3.y;
        var y4:Number=p4.y;
        var px:Number=((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(x3-x4)-(x1-x2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4));
        var py:Number=((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4));
        var segment1Len:Number=Math.pow(p1.x-p2.x,2)+Math.pow(p1.y-p2.y,2);
        var segment2Len:Number=Math.pow(p3.x-p4.x,2)+Math.pow(p3.y-p4.y,2);
        if (Math.pow(p1.x-px,2)+Math.pow(p1.y-py,2)>segment1Len) {
            return null;
        }
        if (Math.pow(p2.x-px,2)+Math.pow(p2.y-py,2)>segment1Len) {
            return null;
        }
        if (Math.pow(p3.x-px,2)+Math.pow(p3.y-py,2)>segment2Len) {
            return null;
        }
        if (Math.pow(p4.x-px,2)+Math.pow(p4.y-py,2)>segment2Len) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Point(px,py);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of good tutorials to be found on that site, I do recommend it.

Just wrote a quick function which does what you are looking for:

```
private function fillIntersection(p,startN,endN):void{
    tailCanvas.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF,0.5);
    tailCanvas.graphics.moveTo(p.x,p.y);

    for (var i:int=endN; i<startN; i++) {
        tailCanvas.graphics.lineTo(nodes[i].x,nodes[i].y);
    }

    tailCanvas.graphics.lineTo(nodes[startN].x,nodes[startN].y);
    tailCanvas.graphics.endFill();
}
```

And you should run this after: `if (p!=null) {` (Line 34)

Like so:

```
if (p!=null) {
        fillIntersection(p,i,j);
        tailCanvas.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
```

To explain how it works, the function is given the points of the line to fill, and the exact point of the collision, it then loops through them and draws a filled in polygon.

(im sure there are better ways of doing it, but it works and is easy to understand)

Comment: Thanks Michael it works! The only thing I changed was I removed this line - tailCanvas.graphics.beginFill(0x000000); - after p!=null as it was adding a black fill outside of the loop. Thanks again.